# Continuity of a multivariable function with "parts"

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I'm trying to solve if $f$ is continuous:

$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
 x^3 + y^3 &\text{if }y>0 \\
  x^2 &\text{if }y ≤ 0
       \end{cases}
$$

I have seen that 
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} x^3+y^3 = \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} x^2 = 0$$
But I don't know if this is sufficient to say that the function is continous

Thanks

Comment: No, that is not sufficient, as it only considers continuity at one point. What definition of continuity are you working with?

Comment: I want to know the continuity in R^2

Comment: What does '$f$ is continuous' mean for you? On the most basic level, you need to think 'this is what the function would need to satisfy to be continuous' and then work out whether or not it satisfies that condition.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $a$ be a number **other than** $0$ or $1$. Then the limit as $(x,y)$ approaches $(a,0)$ of $f(x,y)$ does not exist, and so in particular is not equal to $f(a,0)$.

If you need details about the non-existence, please leave a message.

Comment: I don't see it :(

Comment: We have $f(a,0)=a^2$.  As $(x,y)$ approaches $(a,0)$, with $y$ approaching $0$ **from above**, $f(x,y)$ approaches $a^3+0^3$. So the only way $f$ can be continuous at $(a,0)$ is if $a^2=a^3$, that is, if $a=0$ or $a=1$.  By the way, our function is continuous everywhere else, that is, at all $(x,y)$ with $y\ne 0$, and at $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$\lim_{y\to 0+}f(-1,y)=-1\ ,\qquad \lim_{y\to 0-}f(-1,y)=1\ .$$
This shows that  $\lim_{(x,y)\to(-1,0)} f(x,y)$ does not exist. Therefore $f$ is not continuous on all of ${\mathbb R}^2$.